# Do I need transactional queues in Microservices?

Tags: java, transactions, microservices, message-queue

I'm learning about microservices and I understand that in my scenario I want microservices to communicate with each other using message queues, with persistence. That means if the instance crashes and the message is not consummed, it will be consumed when the instance bounces back (or maybe by another instance).

Now, since these messages are critical, shouldn't they be transactional and participate in the **micro** database transaction? I see examples using Kafka or RabbitMQ but these queue implementations don't implement transactions. If they don't do it there's a clear chance some messages could be lost.

Are transactions really needed for microservices at all? Or should I design my microservices in a resilient way so they can lose information, and recover from this scenario?

Maybe my question doesn't make sense. Maybe I'm still thinking in the "monolithic" way where isolation, locking, and transactions are king.

Comment: I think all queues support 'acknowledgment' (or some other action that will update offset) Basically if you need to be sure that message is received and handled your flow will be: 1. poll 2. handle 3. acknowledge

Comment: In case of crush on (1) and (2) you have acknowledgment (3). If your process is crushed before sending acknowledgment message Broker still will be thinking that message not handled by client.
About (3) - I actually was thinking that this step could rise your concerns and unfortunately it is out of my league to disperse it.

Comment: I guess you are aware about distributed transactions !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Ivan Baranuk said in the comment. Most message broker has `acknowledgement`.  and deadletter queue (DLQ) too.

As long as the crashes happened before the `acknowledgement` (could be handled by the library you are using or you could handle it manually), you would not lose your message, since it will got re-queued. If the crashes still happens after several times and it exceed `maxRetryAttempt` it will be passed to DLQ for you to handle it.

Just think like queue acknowledgement is equivalent to DB commit.

extra: I do think DB transactional is important when consuming message. To handle cases where you have multiple DB writes when consuming message and then on the middle of the process your app crash. When it crashed, the message would not be `ack`-ed and it will got re-queued and will get consumed again later on. It is to prevent double write on the second time the message is consumed.

Comment: I think you are right. I've read quite a bit these last days, and the whole point is to avoid the "safe and slow" technology of 2PC (e.g. JMS). Now, with IDEMPOTENT messages and the ACK strategy you indicate there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question but could be phrased better. I assume you are asking what happens when the worker node that handles the message writes some data to a database and then crashes before it can finish writing the remainder of the data to the database. In other words, the worker node consuming the message crashes at some point before it is able to finish processing the whole message. We are left in a situation where the data in the database is corrupted because only some writes to the database have been performed but not all of the writes that were expected. A good analogy would be saying instructions for something over the phone and the call gets cut off midway. What does the recipient of the call do? Cancel every instruction that was performed before call got cut off or redial the caller to continue from where the call was cut off? What if redialing is not possible because there is no caller ID hence no number to redial?

We now have two options: 1) discard the writes that have taken place so that we can have a clean slate and can restart processing from the beginning, or 2) figure out what has been already written and continue from there.

If option 1 - you need figure out what object the database writes were taking place on and delete that object entry completely from the database. The trick here is keeping track of the unique identifier of that object while consuming the message during processing. You need some form of separate persistent storage for that, such as a cache or other kind of key/value store.

If option 2 - you need to not only figure out the unique identifier of the object but keep a running log of what actions are performed on that object in the database. This is more work and may leave you with objects in the database that are left in their incomplete state and waste space and make database administration harder to perform.